# Is it possible to execute react-native JavaScript code from Swift within an extension target, such as iOS Widgets?

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm trying to implement the new ios17 interactive widgets in my react-native app using Swift. Specifically, I want to execute JavaScript code from my main react-native app when a user interacts with the widget. What approach should I take to achieve this? I have attempted to dispatch an event using RCTEventEmitter (following this instructions: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript), but it appears to be unavailable from an extension target.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by levering both `NotificationCenter` and `RCTEventEmitter`.

Here is an example:

```
// LiveActivityManager.swift
import Foundation
import ActivityKit

@available(iOS 16.2, *)
@objc(LiveActivityManager)
class LiveActivityManager: RCTEventEmitter {
  private var liveActivity: Activity<LiveActivityAttributes>?
  
  @objc
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    return ["TriggerEvent"]
  }
  
  @objc(startActivity)
  func startActivity() {
    if ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled,
       liveActivity == nil {
      
      let activityAttributes = LiveActivityAttributes()
      let initialContent = ActivityContent(state: LiveActivityAttributes.ContentState(),
                                           staleDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60))
      
      do{
        liveActivity = try Activity<LiveActivityAttributes>.request(attributes: activityAttributes, content: initialContent,  pushType: nil)
        
        // Lisent for live activity button pressed events
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.send),
                                           name: Notification.Name("TriggerEvent"),
                                           object: nil)
        
      }catch{
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Sending an event to react with the same name as the notification
  @objc func send(_ notification: Notification) {
    sendEvent(withName: notification.name.rawValue , body: nil)
  }

}
```

In the example above we are using the `NotificationCenter` as a lose couple between your app and the extension and then you are using the sendEvent from the `RCTEventEmitter` to communicate back to react native (you can find various examples on how to integrate the react native part)

Then you need to make an `AppIntent` for the button you are intending to use, make sure this `AppIntent` has a target membership to both your main project and the live activity extension or it won't work:

```
// AppIntent.swift
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import ActivityKit

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct ActionButtonAppIntent: LiveActivityIntent{
  init() {
  }
  
  @Parameter(title: "eventName")
  var eventName: String
  
  init(eventName:String){
      self.eventName = eventName
  }
  
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Live Activity"

  static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
  
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    NotificationCenter.default.post( name: Notification.Name(eventName), object: nil)
    return .result()
  }
}
```